# Screen jumps when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need some help troubleshooting http://mincovlaw.com/goodies/standard_agreements

If viewed on a regular screen (over 800px in width), when I scroll the page, it suddenly jumps up & down (just a little bit).

I was about to write that this is the only page that behaves this way, until I noticed that in fact ALL pages have the same weird behavior.

This behavior does not exist in the mobile version of the website.

Can you please help me figure this out?

Thank you!

UPDATE: This is the function that messes up the scrolling:

```
function revealmobilemenu() {
    var iebody=(document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body;
    var dsoctop=document.all? iebody.scrollTop : pageYOffset;
    scroll_timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (dsoctop > 500) {
            revealmobilemenunow();
        } else {
            hidemobilemenunow();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

When disabled, the scrolling works fine, but then the mobile version does not show the back to top button.

UPDATE 2: SOLVED: The problem was that the desktop version did not have `position:fixed` for the `BackToTop` div, so when it turned from `display:none` to `display:block`, it actually added to the window. Fixed with adding `position:fixed` for the desktop css.

Comment: It is one of your JS files. Disable them one by one to decipher the troublesome script.

Comment: please see the edit - i see which function messes this up, but I don't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: I'm delighted you solved your problem, but could you **add your solution as an answer** and **accept it** so that future users with the same questions will see the answer straight away?

Comment: Please **DO NOT** add "solved" to the title/post!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the desktop version did not have position:fixed for the BackToTop div, so when it turned from display:none to display:block, it actually added to the window. Fixed with adding position:fixed for the desktop css.